# Removing stopwords from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I need to remove stopwords from a CSV file.
The file looks like this :

```
 "word word word","category"
 "word word word","category"
 "word word word","category"
```

My code is the following :

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
f = codecs.open("petitions_train.csv", "r", "utf-8")
non_filtered = f.read()
f.close()

stop = stopwords.words("english")

filtered = [w for w in non_filtered if not w in stop]
print(filtered)
```

The result isn't what I expect as it is printing characters one by one :

```
...  ' ', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'f', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'e', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'ç', 'a', 'i', 'e', ' ', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'k', 'é', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'i', ' ', ' ', 'v', 'i', 'a', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'p', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b
', ' ', 'h', 'ô', 'e', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'i', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'e', 'e', 'r', 'g', 'i', 'e', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'u', 'e', ' ', 'ê', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'u', ' ', 'é', 'p', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'e', ' ',
'b', 'r', 'u', 'x', 'e', 'e', ' ', 'u', ' ', 'o', 'u', 'r', ' ', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'e', ' ', '2', '0', '1', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'i', ' ', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'e', 'u', 'x', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'e', ' ', '2', '0'
, '1', '7', ' ', ' ', '2', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '"', ',', '"', 'p', 'o', 'r', '"', '\r', '\n']
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Show what you are expecting and what you are receiving with a [mcve].  What does `stopwords.words()` do?

Comment: Sorry about the bad presentation. Edited it. 
stopwords.words return a list of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse (split) the sentences into words. Use tokenize or split.

Also, please clarify your question by adding:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.